# CMake's find_program / find_path / find_* and in-source build

Tags: cmake, flatbuffers

What is the right way of saying to `find_*` functions that a library/path/whatever they are supposed to find, are built (and therefore available) in-source?

In particular, I am trying to follow [flatbuffer instructions](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_building.html):

> If you want to use FlatBuffers in a project which already uses CMake, then a more robust and flexible approach is to build FlatBuffers as part of that project directly. This is done by making the FlatBuffers source code available to the main build and adding it using CMake's `add_subdirectory()` command.
>
> Suppose you put FlatBuffers source code in directory `${FLATBUFFERS_SRC_DIR}`. To build it as part of your project, add following code to your CMakeLists.txt file:

```
# Add FlatBuffers directly to our build. This defines the `flatbuffers` target.
add_subdirectory(${FLATBUFFERS_SRC_DIR}
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/flatbuffers-build
                 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
# Now simply link against flatbuffers as needed to your already declared target.
# The flatbuffers target carry header search path automatically if CMake > 2.8.11.
target_link_libraries(own_project_target PRIVATE flatbuffers)
```

It works perfectly fine, but then, to generate c++ code, I need to invoke `flatc` executable built in the previous step. In order not to do it manually, I would like to utilise existing cmake function defined in their codebase - [CMake/FindFlatBuffers.cmake](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/CMake/FindFlatBuffers.cmake), but the problem is that in the very beginning of the file they are trying to find `flatc` executable:

```
find_program(FLATBUFFERS_FLATC_EXECUTABLE NAMES flatc)
find_path(FLATBUFFERS_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h)
```

which, of course, fails, since I disabled installing of flatbuffers.

Is there an easy solution?

Comment: Did you see the FlatBuffers usage in [this](https://github.com/ogmacorp/OgmaNeo/blob/3edd6b3e9ff044ab7a924d1871c92b8762390379/CMakeLists.txt#L152) project? Although, this project uses `find_package()`, which sets the `FLATBUFFERS_FLATC_EXECUTABLE` variable for you, they have the hard-coded path to the executable in the `else` condition, in the case that `find_package()` fails.

Comment: Thanks! So it looks like there is no way of "circumventing" `find_*` function, and instead, people set variables it was going to find, manually.